# Capturing Microphone Audio On Finger Press Until Finger Is Removed In Mobile Web Browser

Tags: javascript, html, speech-to-text, mobile-website, microphone

I am working on a project in which I need the user to be able to hold down the screen in a web browser (Ideally works on Desktop but mainly mobile), record the user speaking while the finger is pressed and when the finger is lifted send this audio data to be converted to text using a speech-to-text service.

I can easily track when a finger is pressed and lifted on the screen, the thing I am having issues with is finding a way to stop and start recording easily and it appears Safari on IOS isn't supported by a lot of microphone libraries. The ones I have tried use a built in GUI and I haven't been able to figure out how to remove that GUI and just use the data.

Does anyone have any recommendations or know of any resources for how I can accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use touchstart and touchend events for that.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: This has a lot of support for both Mobile and Desktop which is great, I'm assuming this Is just for registering finger press though as I don't see anything on the page which points to microphone use which is more of what I'm looking for. This will be helpful though thanks!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-audio Maybe this is something for you. If you want to use the microphone.
Or this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API